# What's the differences between VirtualAlloc and HeapAlloc?

Tags: winapi, memory, heap-memory, new-operator

There are lots of method to allocate memory in Windows environment, such as `VirtualAlloc`, `HeapAlloc`, `malloc`, `new`.

Thus, what's the difference among them?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Each API is for different uses. Each one also requires that you use the correct deallocation/freeing function when you're done with the memory.

#### VirtualAlloc

A low-level, Windows API that provides lots of options, but is mainly useful for people in fairly specific situations. Can only allocate memory in (edit: not 4KB) larger chunks. There are situations where you need it, but you'll know when you're in one of these situations. One of the most common is if you have to share memory directly with another process. Don't use it for general-purpose memory allocation. Use `VirtualFree` to deallocate.

#### HeapAlloc

Allocates whatever size of memory you ask for, not in big chunks than `VirtualAlloc`. `HeapAlloc` knows when it needs to call `VirtualAlloc` and does so for you automatically. Like `malloc`, but is Windows-only, and provides a couple more options. Suitable for allocating general chunks of memory. Some Windows APIs may require that you use this to allocate memory that you pass to them, or use its companion `HeapFree` to free memory that they return to you.

#### malloc

The C way of allocating memory. Prefer this if you are writing in C rather than C++, and you want your code to work on e.g. Unix computers too, or someone specifically says that you need to use it. Doesn't initialise the memory.  Suitable for allocating general chunks of memory, like `HeapAlloc`. A simple API. Use `free` to deallocate. Visual C++'s `malloc` calls `HeapAlloc`.

#### new

The C++ way of allocating memory. Prefer this if you are writing in C++. It puts an object or objects into the allocated memory, too. Use `delete` to deallocate (or `delete[]` for arrays). Visual studio's `new` calls `HeapAlloc`, and then maybe initialises the objects, depending on how you call it.

In recent C++ standards (C++11 and above), if you have to manually use `delete`, you're doing it wrong and should use a *smart pointer* like `unique_ptr` instead. From C++14 onwards, the same can be said of `new` (replaced with functions such as `make_unique()`).

---

There are also a couple of other similar functions like `SysAllocString` that you may be told you have to use in specific circumstances.

Comment: Doug: VirtualAlloc is not strictly limited to 4kb allocations, it's the size returned by GetSystemInfo(), SYSTEM_INFO::dwAllocationGranularity. It's actually _RARELY_ 4kb.
On my host, it's 64k, I suspect the same for you.  4KB is the minimum page size entry for the various discriptor tables in the x86 ABI.  4KB is the smallest size which can be indapendently permissioned, R/W/X, however it is not of any significance to VirtualAlloc.  If you refer to the VirtualAlloc documentation, there is also the LARGE_PAGES option ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366568(VS.85).aspx ).

Comment: do you know why DirectShow uses VirtualAlloc to allocate memory buffers for media instead of using malloc?

Comment: Aviad: DirectShow uses virtual alloc to reserve memory so it can pass flags required for performance optimizations, things like not pageable or so that it can reserve physical pages which can improve performacne if your hardware can support it.

Comment: @RandomNickName42: this isn't right.  The allocation start address is always aligned with the granularity (64KB), but the allocation length is rounded to the page size (4KB).  In effect, address space is reserved in 64KB chunks, but committed in 4KB chunks.  The alignment of the start address isn't usually that interesting so from most points of view VirtualAlloc works in 4KB chunks.  These details only become important if you're trying to do lots of small VirtualAllocs (you'll run out of address space) or something fancy (like adjacent but separate allocations).

Comment: I thought malloc/new/CRT called HeapAlloc once then used its own algorithms to return blocks of memory from the HeapAlloc memory block?

Comment: 2arx: I'd like to write similar thing. "In effect, address space is reserved in 64KB chunks, but committed in 4KB chunks. ", yeah it is strong limitation.

Comment: " Don't use it for general-purpose memory allocation. " Ridiculous statement with no reasoning behind it.

Comment: "Some Windows APIs may require that you use [`HeapAlloc`] to allocate memory that you pass to them, or use its companion `HeapFree` to free memory that they return to you." <<< Any examples of this?

Answer (score 62):

It is very important to understand the distinction between memory allocation APIs (in Windows) if you plan on using a language that requires memory management (like C or C++.) And the best way to illustrate it IMHO is with a diagram:

[image]

*Note that this is a very simplified, Windows-specific view.*

The way to understand this diagram is that the higher on the diagram a memory allocation method is, the *higher level* implementation it uses. But let's start from the bottom.

### Kernel-Mode Memory Manager

It provides all memory reservations & allocations for the operating system, as well as support for *memory-mapped files*, *shared memory*, *copy-on-write* operations, etc. It's not directly accessible from the user-mode code, so I'll skip it here.

### [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) / [VirtualFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892(v=vs.85).aspx)

These are the *lowest level* APIs available from the [user mode](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode/). The `VirtualAlloc` function basically invokes [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566416(v=vs.85).aspx) that in turn does a quick *[syscall](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html)* to `ring0` to relegate further processing to the kernel memory manager. It is also the fastest method to reserve/allocate block of new memory from all available in the user mode.

But it comes with two main conditions:

- It only allocates memory blocks aligned on the system granularity boundary.
- It only allocates memory blocks of the size that is the multiple of the system granularity.

So what is this *system granularity*? You can get it by calling [GetSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx). It is returned as the [`dwAllocationGranularity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter. Its value is implementation (and possibly hardware) specific, but on many 64-bit Windows systems it is set at `0x10000` bytes, or `64K`.

So what all this means, is that if you try to allocate, say just an 8 byte memory block with `VirtualAlloc`:

```
void* pAddress = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 8, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

If successful, `pAddress` will be aligned on the `0x10000` byte boundary. And even though you requested only 8 bytes, the actual memory block that you will get will be the entire `page` (or, something like `4K` bytes. The exact page size is returned in the [`dwPageSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter.) But, on top of that, the entire memory block spanning `0x10000` bytes (or `64K` in most cases) from `pAddress` **will not** be available for any further allocations. So in a sense, by allocating 8 bytes you could as well be asking for 65536.

So the moral of the story here is not to substitute `VirtualAlloc` for generic memory allocations in your application. It must be used for very specific cases, as is done with the *heap* below. (Usually for reserving/allocating large blocks of memory.)

*Using `VirtualAlloc` incorrectly can lead to severe memory fragmentation.*

### [HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx) / [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx) / [HeapFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701(v=vs.85).aspx) / [HeapDestroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366700(v=vs.85).aspx)

In a nutshell, the *heap* functions are basically a wrapper for `VirtualAlloc` function. Other answers here provide a pretty good concept of it. I'll add that, in a very simplistic view, the way *heap* works is this:

- `HeapCreate` reserves a large block of virtual memory by calling `VirtualAlloc` internally (or `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` to be specific). It also sets up an internal data structure that can track further smaller size allocations within the reserved block of virtual memory.
- Any calls to `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree` do not actually allocate/free any new memory (unless, of course the request exceeds what has been already reserved in `HeapCreate`) but instead they *meter out* (or `commit`) a previously reserved large chunk, by dissecting it into smaller memory blocks that a user requests.
- `HeapDestroy` in turn calls `VirtualFree` that actually frees the virtual memory.

So all this makes *heap* functions perfect candidates for generic memory allocations in your application. It is great for arbitrary size memory allocations. But a small price to pay for the convenience of the *heap* functions is that they introduce a slight overhead over `VirtualAlloc` when reserving larger blocks of memory.

Another good thing about *heap* is that you don't really need to create one. It is generally created for you when your process starts. So one can access it by calling [GetProcessHeap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

### [malloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) / free

Is a language-specific wrapper for the *heap* functions. Unlike `HeapAlloc`, `HeapFree`, etc. these functions will work not only if your code is compiled for Windows, but also for other operating systems (such as Linux, etc.)

This is a recommended way to allocate/free memory if you program in C. (Unless, you're coding a specific kernel mode device driver.)

### [new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/) / delete

Come as a *high level* (well, for `C++`) memory management operators. They are specific for the `C++` language, and like `malloc` for `C`, are also the wrappers for the `heap` functions. They also have a whole bunch of their own code that deals `C++`-specific initialization of constructors, deallocation in destructors, raising an exception, etc.

These functions are a recommended way to allocate/free memory and objects if you program in `C++`.

---

*Lastly, one comment I want to make about what has been said in other responses about using `VirtualAlloc` to share memory between processes. `VirtualAlloc` by itself does not allow sharing of its reserved/allocated memory with other processes. For that one needs to use [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) API that can create a named virtual memory block that can be shared with other processes. It can also map a file on disk into virtual memory for read/write access. But that is another topic.*

Comment: This is absolute beast of an answer! I thank you greatly. I was using `VirtualAlloc` to allocate strings for my custom library for all the strings bigger than 1024 bytes and was wondering why my lib is 13 times slower than std::string :)

Comment: Also, I want to add that `VirtualAlloc` always zeroes allocated memory. And this is also huge performance loss.

Answer (score 31):

`VirtualAlloc` is a specialized allocation of the OS virtual memory (VM) system. Allocations in the VM system must be made at an allocation granularity which (the allocation granularity) is architecture dependent. Allocation in the VM system is one of the most basic forms of memory allocation.  VM allocations can take several forms, memory is not necessarily dedicated or physically backed in RAM (though it can be).  VM allocation is typically a *special purpose* type of allocation, either because of the allocation has to

- be very large,
- needs to be shared,
- must be aligned on a particular value (performance reasons) or
- the caller need not use all of this memory at once...
- etc...

`HeapAlloc` is essentially what `malloc` and `new` both eventually call.  It is designed to be very fast and usable under many different types of scenarios of a general purpose allocation.  It is the "Heap" in a classic sense.  Heaps are actually setup by a `VirtualAlloc`, which is what is used to *initially* reserve allocation space from the OS. After the space is initialized by `VirtualAlloc`, various tables, lists and other data structures are configured to maintain and control the operation of the HEAP. Some of that operation is in the form of dynamically sizing (growing and shrinking) the heap, adapting the heap to particular usages (frequent allocations of some size), etc..

`new` and `malloc` are somewhat the same, `malloc` is essentially an exact call into `HeapAlloc( heap-id-default )`; `new` however, can [additionally] configure the allocated memory for C++ *objects*.  For a given object, C++ will store vtables on the heap for each caller. These vtables are redirects for execution and form part of what gives C++ it's OO characteristics like inheritance, function overloading, etc...

Some other common allocation methods like `_alloca()` and `_malloca()` are *stack* based; FileMappings are really allocated with `VirtualAlloc` and set with particular bit flags which designate those mappings to be of type `FILE`.

Most of the time, you should allocate memory in a way which is consistent with the use of that memory ;).  `new` in C++, `malloc` for C, `VirtualAlloc` for massive or IPC cases.

*** Note, large memory allocations done by `HeapAlloc` are actually shipped off to `VirtualAlloc` after some size (couple hundred k or 16 MB or something I forget, but fairly big :) ).

*** EDIT
I briefly remarked about IPC and `VirtualAlloc`, there is also something very neat about a related `VirtualAlloc` which none of the responders to this question have discussed.

`VirtualAlloc`**Ex** is what one process can use to allocate memory in an address space of a *different* process.  Most typically, this is used <s>in combination</s> to get remote execution in the context of another process via **CreateRemoteThread** (similar to `CreateThread`, the thread is just run in the other process).

Answer (score 7):

In outline:

- VirtualAlloc, HeapAlloc etc. are Windows APIs that allocate memory of various types from the OS directly. VirtualAlloc manages pages in the Windows virtual memory system, while  HeapAlloc allocates from a specific OS heap. Frankly, you are unlikely to ever need to use eiither of them.
- malloc is a Standard C (and C++) library function that allocates memory to your process. Implementations of malloc will typically use one of the OS APIs to create a pool of memory when your app starts and then allocate from it as you make malloc requests
- new is a Standard C++ operator which allocates memory and then calls constructors appropriately on that memory. It may be implemented in terms of malloc or in terms of the OS APIs, in which case it too will typically create a memory pool on application startup.

Answer (score 5):

`VirtualAlloc` ===> `sbrk()` under UNIX

`HeapAlloc` ====> `malloc()` under UNIX

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

`VirtualAlloc` => Allocates straight into virtual memory, you reserve/commit in blocks. This is great for large allocations, for example large arrays.

`HeapAlloc` / `new` => allocates the memory on the default heap (or any other heap that you may create). This allocates per object and is great for smaller objects. The default heap is serializable therefore it has guarantee thread allocation (this can cause some issues on high performance scenarios and that's why you can create your own heaps).

`malloc` => uses the C runtime heap, similar to `HeapAlloc` but it is common for compatibility scenarios.

In a nutshell, the heap is just a chunk of virtual memory that is governed by a heap manager (rather than raw virtual memory)

The last model on the memory world is memory mapped files, this scenario is great for large chunk of data (like large files). This is used internally when you open an EXE (it does not load the EXE in memory, just creates a memory mapped file).