# OS memory allocation

Tags: operating-system, dynamic-memory-allocation

How does OS allocate memory to processes?
I mean for example in unix familly does OS use malloc function for this allocation?

Does memory schaduler use malloc func?
What is the routine that do this allocation in OS?
Thank you

Comment: What is a "memory schaduler"?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530355/is-memory-allocation-a-system-call

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit of a chicken&egg problem if the OS used `malloc`, because `malloc` generally has to use the OS to get memory (unless `malloc` can reuse memory that you `free`d before.

Also, `malloc` works with byte granularity. Every modern OS uses "virtual memory" made out of pages. A typical page is 4 kB, not one byte. Actual page sizes depend on CPU support.

The routines used in the OS are specific to the OS, internal to the OS, and not relevant to the application programmer. The only thing you *might* need to know is how to ask the OS - but often you don't program against the OS directly. Your language runtime will handle that for you (see again `malloc`).

Comment: OS use the routine to allocate memory and assembly routine use machine instructin.

Comment: It seems that for example in X86 instruction set   there is no instruction for this specific task (of course it has)

Comment: @RezaFarshad: On x86, pages are managed in the page table. That's an in-memory structure, so `MOV` will work just fine. No special instruction needed.

Answer (score 0):

> How does OS allocate memory to processes?

OSes use their own memory allocator for choosing an unused page in virtual memory. The virtual memory space is the same for each process but each process has a different set of page tables that is switched by changing the value in the Base Pointer Register which is the register that contains the physical address of the root of page tables (the address of the first byte of the first level of page tables).

Each core of the CPU has its own set of registers and each core executes the instructions of one process at a time. The OS uses timers for process scheduling where it gives a time slice to each process and lets them execute on a specific core. Timers are hardware mechanisms that raise asynchronous interrupts so the OS can just schedule a process to the core and wait that the timer triggers an interrupt to notify that its time slice is over. The OS is then free to schedule another process on that core after changing the Base Pointer Register's value to the new set of page tables.

That way, the OS can choose any page in virtual memory as long as the address range in virtual memory that constitutes the page translates to a different range of the physical memory or RAM. It is the CPU that reads page tables to translate virtual addresses to physical ones so it is an hardware mechanism. The management required by the OS is changing the values in the page tables that are stored in physical memory (so simply use MOV instructions) to make sure the translations land at different page frames (physical memory range of addresses).

The process makes a syscall by placing arguments in standard registers (the standard is System V on Linux) along with the syscall number for memory allocation in another standard register. The process then executes a CPU instruction that jumps to an address specified by the OS in a special syscall register provided by the CPU or triggers an interrupt depending on the CPU mechanisms that are available (its architecture e.g. ARM, x86, RISC-V, etc). The syscall handler of the OS (its first instruction is at the address stored in that special register) then figures out what to do based on the number of the syscall and the arguments provided. For a memory allocation, it will figure out some pages in virtual memory that are available, change the page table to allow the process access to it and return the calling process after placing the first address of that page in a return register or the stack. The instructions in the function can assume that the value in that register contain an address or an error code and access all addresses in the size of the requested allocation e.g. if the process asked for 1 page the instructions later in the function can access everything within `returned_address + page_size amount of bytes`.

> I mean for example in unix familly does OS use malloc function for this allocation?

The function malloc is a c standard function that is implemented by the standard library of your OS. The standard library uses a syscall to request memory. Independently of the language you use, the OS provides syscalls that are useful or required based on current usage for computers. If a syscall is useful or required, the OS has to provide it regardless of a high level language requiring it or not. For memory allocation, the OS has to provide the service and the high level language has nothing to do with it. The high level language is an abstraction that will use syscalls to get the job done based on what its standard requires. For malloc, it requires that the process can be provided with a range of addresses within which it can read and write so the standard library uses features available on a certain OS to provide it.

> OS use the routine to allocate memory and assembly routine use machine instructin.

That doesn't make any sense. Computers are electrical devices they work with electricity. It is electronic circuits that represent numbers with 2 states which are represented in abstraction with ones and zeroes. The actual electric representation of a one or a zero is determined by the hardware and chosen based on a bunch of criterias such as power consumption, size of components e.g. can I use this certain voltage with a transistor at nanometer scale?, etc.

Computers move data around electrically and make calculations on that data and that's the only thing that they do. When you see external effects on the computer, e.g. typing on a keyboard and see something change on the screen, this is data moving around representing the key you pressed, electronic circuits changing the data (the image rendered on the screen represented with data) and eventually your screen showing that new image after the graphics card interacted electronically with your screen to make it show that new image.

Higher level languages are textual including assembly. A programming language is a standard which is textual. The languages are defined by what lines of code they support. The compiler of a language is an implementation of that language. The coder writes text which is lines of code and calls the compiler which reads the text (your code). It will then write an executable that contains instructions that will achieve the result specified in the standard (the language such as C, C++, Java, Python, etc.) for a certain architecture that it targets such as x86, ARM, etc. It also has to adjust to the OS platform for everything that relates to syscalls but this is often abstracted away by the standard library. The instructions in the executable call a function in the library and this function does the more lower level job of properly making syscalls to achieve the proper result.

Comment: Wow wonderful answer.you mean in each entry of process table there is a address of begining of a process.and program counter points to this entry so jump to this address.before all this loader must load the program code to memory and probably it uses MOV instruction to do this.Move data ( data is program codes) from hard disk buffer to registers and memory.

Comment: A process really is just a data structure held in kernel areas of the virtual memory with different page tables since PTI (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427689/linux-kernel-virtual-memory-space-address-handling-and-virtual-memory-confusion/77491765#77491765). That data structure specifies the memory allocated to the process in ranges of virtual addresses e.g. from SOME_ADDRESS to SOME_OTHER_ADRESS is allocated to your process. The data structure most lilely points to other data structures for threads (Thread Control Blocks or TCB).

Comment: Each thread belongs to a process and shares its address space. It depends on implementation (between OSes) but the process could not specify the value for registers and let TCBs handle it. When a thread is running on a core, the values for its registers in its TCB are not valid. When it gets switched out, its current registers are saved in its TCB for its next scheduled run.

Comment: The Program Counter cannot be modified explicitely with a mov so you have to jump to an address using ```jmp``` or something similar. It is essentially like you mentionned : the executable file which contains the compiled program's code mentions a first instruction and the OS will jump to it after loading the code in main memory or RAM from the hard-disk. For loading memory from an hard-disk, see another of my answer on cs.stackexchange.com : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142525/data-transfer-between-cpu-ram-and-secondary-storage/142553#142553