# does rtlheapalloc calls virtualalloc internally?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

Does RtlHeapAlloc calls VirtuallAlloc internally? if not what is the implementation of it ? can anyone offer some details or links about it? i didn't find too much useful information from google. thanks!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872072/whats-the-differences-between-virtualalloc-and-heapalloc

Comment: There won't be documentation. It's implementation detail.