# How does the operating system determine which region to allocate when lpAddress is null in VirtualAlloc

Tags: windows, memory-management, virtualalloc

When the `lpAddress` parameter to a `VirtualAlloc` function call is null, how does the OS determine which virtual address space region to allocate?

Comment: Would I be correct in interpreting this question as 'How does malloc work?'?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the reason *why* you're asking this question? Why do you think you need to know this information? Why is it relevant to the design of your application, or your call to the function? If you care about the region, you should pass something for `lpAddress`. If you pass `NULL`, then you don't care by definition.

Comment: @Patashu No, you'd be confusing the OS's low-level virtual memory system with a fine-grained general-purpose allocator in the C standard library.

Comment: Short version: the OS allocates the new block in any suitable currently unused region of the virtual address space.

Answer (score 1):

When **VirtualAlloc** function is given **NULL** for **lpAddress** parameter, the function will allocate in another **Virtual Page** ahead, and the **allocation size** will be rounded to that page boundary.

Resources:

- [VirtualAlloc function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [A stackoverflow post that has related useful info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872094/2128327)

Hope this helps